# Get Element From iFrame Returns Null/undefined?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I've followed what everybody else has said for the others to do, but I'm getting a "null" or "undefined".

```
var frame=win.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0];
var innerDoc = (frame.contentDocument)
 ? frame.contentDocument
 : frame.contentWindow.document;
alert(innerDoc.getElementById("input"));
```

Comment: What is your question?  And do you really have an element with `id="input"`?

Comment: What is undefined? getElementsByTageName, the NodeList, frame, innerDoc, getElementById, the alert argument?

Comment: Do you know about the same-origin-policy?

Comment: My question is to why this may not be working.

When I alert innerDoc.getElementById("input"), I get "null", even though the element exists on the page that I'm accessing.

Yes, they are the same domain, and no, I do not know of this same-origin-policy.

Comment: what is "win" here? try with var frame=document.getElementsByTagName ..instead of "win".

Comment: "win" is a variable that is passed through the function. Basically, win (if I even remember with all this coding) is supposed to be a div element.

You can view the source of my project here: http://nintendos.t15.org/index.dsos

Comment: Is the iframe document loaded when you are attempting to access the input element?

Answer (score 2):

Try this example

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Iframe Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload= function(){
        var frame=document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0]; 
        var innerDoc = (frame.contentDocument)  ? frame.contentDocument  : frame.contentWindow.document; 
        alert(innerDoc.getElementById("input")); 
    }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <iframe src="test.htm" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the source of test.htm

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>A test Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="input">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

It worked in my local machine.

Comment: I'm working for a specific browser, so there's no fuss with whether it's contentWindow or contentDocument.

Your script made my entire page unusable for some reason. A syntax error I can't seem to find. 
BUT! When I simply do this:

var frame=win.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0];
var innerDoc = frame.contentDocument;
alert(innerDoc);

The script alerts "Object HTMLDocument". That tells me that it's correct, non?

I guess the real question is: if it's saying that it's an HTMLDocument object, what should I put DIRECTLY after innerDoc? Do I bother to put ".document.whatever" or just ".whatever"?

Comment: @RickyAYoder, Sorry to hear that. I have tried the above one in IE9 and FireFox and worked perfectly i.e. it returns the element in Iframe. Are you calling your script when the DOM is ready/not ready. If possible, please check that.